# Modify Backup Script to Run 4x/week Instead of Daily

Tags: backup

I'm looking at modifying a backup script that has been setup for me on my server. The script currently runs each morning to backup all of my domains under the `/var/www/vhosts/` directory and I'd like to have it run only four times per week (Sun, Tue, Thu, Sat) instead of daily, if possible. I'm relatively new to the scripting language/commands and was wondering if someone might be able to help me with this? Here is the current script:

```
umask 0077

BPATH="/disk2/backups/vhosts_backups/`date +%w`"
LOG="backup.log"

/bin/rm -rf $BPATH/*

for i in `ls /var/www/vhosts` on 
do
tar czf $BPATH/$i.tgz -C /var/www/vhosts $i 2>>$BPATH/backup.log
done
```

Thank you,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question (in case it could benefit anyone else), it turns out that the backup script was scheduled through crontab, and that's what needed the adjustment. I did `crontab -e` and modified the 4th field below from an * to "0,2,4,6" (for Sun, Tue, Thu, Sat).

```
5  1   *   *   0,2,4,6 /root/scripts/vhosts_backup.sh
```